# Xcopy a folder and subfolders with os.system and python3

Tags: python

Hi I am using python and I want to copy a folder and its subfolder, I am using this code:

```
source = "C:\\boleta_v1\\bd"
target = "C:\\boleta_v1\\" + folder_name

output = os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" /E""" % (source, target))
```

When I see the result, it copied but it just copied the files inside the folder not the folder with the files inside, so I wonder, how can I copy the folder and its subfolder and files inside with os.system in Python

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that Python's built-in `shutil.copytree` can do that, in a system-independent way?  If you insist on using `xcopy`, then you kist need to set `target = "C:\\boleta_v1\\"+folder_name+"\\bd"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mkdir` (or `md`) to create the directory you want. That is:

```
source = "C:\\boleta_v1\\bd"
target = "C:\\boleta_v1\\" + folder_name
target = os.path.join(target, "bd")

os.system("""md "%s" """ % (target))
output = os.system ("""xcopy "%s" "%s" /E""" % (source, target))
```

Comment: It copied the bd folder but it did not copy the subdolders and files inside it

Comment: Note that this approach allows shell injection vulnerabilities if an attacker can choose the `folder_name`; particularly if they can pick a name that contains literal quotes. And even if you don't have attacks on your system, it still means there are filenames your code doesn't work with.